# How to solve "Not allowed to load local resource:" in electron

Tags: reactjs, electron

I am trying to open a PDF file in the browser, from local system. Console throws "Not allowed to load local resource:".Am using electron application and Chakra UI.

Below code works fine and PDF is opening as expected when I disable webSecurity in webPreferences. Since that is not an ideal way to do it, am looking for other solutions.

```
function createWindow() {
  try {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 1280,
      height: 760,
      show: false,
      frame: false,
      autoHideMenuBar: true,
      icon: process.platform === 'linux' ? 'icon' : undefined,
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        contextIsolation: false,
        preload: join(__dirname, '../preload/index'),
        sandbox: false,
        //webSecurity: false,
      },
    });

    // Once the window is ready to show, display it
    mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
      mainWindow.show();
    });

    // Set a handler for opening external URLs
    mainWindow.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(({ url }) => {
      shell.openExternal(url); // Open external URLs in the user's default browser
      return { action: 'allow' }; // Deny opening new windows
    });
```

Below is my Chakra UI code

```
<ChakraLink
                  {...smSemiBold}
                  color="teal.800"
                  data-testid={`${TOP_LEVEL_ID}__link`}
                  href="C://Program Files//Proj//documentation//Guide.pdf"
                  padding="0.5rem 1rem"
                  target="_blank"
                  referrerPolicy="no-referrer"
                >
                  {"click here"}
                </ChakraLink>
```

Comment: Since you control the contents of the renderer process, is there any reason not to use IPC instead of links and overriding the link handlers?